# Some questions about bitwise operators

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, bit-manipulation

I read about bitwise operators today and they seem rather handy to me. I also noticed Apple uses them too, for example with `UIViewAutoresizing`.

In my app I need to keep track of the seven days of the week. Each day can be either enabled or disabled. I used to have seven `BOOL`'s, but now I'm trying to use a single integer for this:

```
enum {
    DaysMonday = 1 << 0,
    DaysTuesday = 1 << 1,
    DaysWednesday = 1 << 2,
    DaysThursday = 1 << 3,
    DaysFriday = 1 << 4,
    DaysSaturday = 1 << 5,
    DaysSunday = 1 << 6
};
typedef NSUInteger Days;
```

My question is, how can I enable/disable those values now? I know I can check a variable `days` for a specific day like this:

```
if (days & DaysThursday) {
    // thursday enabled
}
```

But how do I..

1. enable thursday?
2. disable thursday?
3. toggle thursday?
4. enable all?
5. disable all?

Thank you.

Comment: I'll just leave [this](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) here.

Comment: Harkens back to the days when we spent lots of time seeing how much we could squeeze data. Bitwise operators for on/off situations like this, using two bits for things with 3 or 4 states, etc. I still lean that way sometimes but am much more relaxed about it now that space and bandwidth have increased so dramatically.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with objective-c, but here are the basics when dealing with bitwise operators.

Enable Thursday

```
days = days | DaysThursday;
```

Disable Thursday

```
allDays = DaysMonday | DaysTuesday | ... | DaysSunday;
days = days & (allDays ^ DaysThursday);
// OR
days = days & ~DaysThursday;
```

Toggle Thursday

```
days = days ^ DaysThursday;
```

Enable All

```
allDays = DaysMonday | DaysTuesday | ... | DaysSunday;
days = days | allDays;
// OR
days = allDays;
```

Disable All

```
days = days ^ days;
// OR
days = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks. I added a few more, could you take a look?

Comment: Added the enable all & disable all answers.

Comment: Wouldn't 'Disable Thursday' be better like this?: days = days & !DaysThursday;

Comment: @v01d you should use the bitwise `not` operator, `~` : `days = days & ~DaysThursday;`

Comment: I didn't know that Objective-C has a bitwise not operator

Comment: @Jon it's the C bitwise not operator.  Nothing listed in this question is specific to Objective-C (except `NSUInteger`).

Comment: Awesome, you learn something every day. I had no idea there was a ~ operator. That will save me a lot of debugging confusion later down the track!

Answer (score 3):

```
days = DaysMonday | DaysWednesday | DaysFriday | DaysSaturday;
days = days | DaysThursday;
days = days & ~DaysSaturday;
```